# Como centralizar logo brand no Bootstrap 4 e deixar os itens de menu abaixo?

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

estou realizando um projeto e estou com dificuldade em centralizar o logo e deixar os itens de menu abaixo, de forma que tudo faça parte da navbar e que quando ocorra a quebra para celular tablet, o toggle icon fique na mesma linha do logo, e não abaixo.

**Código:**

```
<!-- Início do Cabeçalho -->
  <header>
    <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-md">
      <div class="container">
        <!-- Logo do Site -->
          <a href="index.html" class="navbar-brand">
            <img src="../assets/img/logo-marca.png" height="75">
          </a>
        <!-- Menu Hamburguer -->
        <button class="navbar-toggler" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#nav-principal">
          <i class="fas fa-bars text-white"></i>
        </button>
        </br>
        <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="nav-principal">
            <ul class="navbar-nav navbar-light ml-auto">
              <li class="nav-item">
                <a href="" class="nav-link"> Início </a>
              </li>
              <li class="nav-item">
                <a href="" class="nav-link"> A Clínica </a>
              </li>
              <li class="nav-item">
                <a href="" class="nav-link"> Tratamentos </a>
              </li>
              <li class="nav-item">
                <a href="" class="nav-link"> Promoções </a>
              </li>
              <li class="nav-item">
                <a href="" class="nav-link"> Contato </a>
              </li>
            </ul>
          </div>
          <!-- Fim do Menu -->
      </div>
    </nav>
  </header>
  <!-- Fim do Cabeçalho -->
```

**Como eu gostaria que ficasse:**

[image: Imagem do Photoshop]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Você pode criar uma regra de media query quando a tela tiver de 768px pra cima, aplicando `flex-direction: column;` na div `.container`. Desta forma, a logo e o menu ficarão alinhados em forma de coluna, um abaixo do outro. Quando a tela for menor que 768px, o menu hambúrguer ficará na mesma linha da logo, pois a div `.container` não será mais em forma de coluna. Veja:

> Não é necessário o `</br>` após o `<button>`.

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.0/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.7.2/css/all.css" integrity="sha384-fnmOCqbTlWIlj8LyTjo7mOUStjsKC4pOpQbqyi7RrhN7udi9RwhKkMHpvLbHG9Sr" crossorigin="anonymous">
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<style>
body{
   background: pink;
}

@media screen and (min-width: 768px) {
   .navbar-expand-md > .container{
      flex-direction: column;
   }
}
</style>


<!-- Início do Cabeçalho -->
  <header>
    <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-md">
      <div class="container">
        <!-- Logo do Site -->
          <a href="index.html" class="navbar-brand">
            <img src="https://www.cleverfiles.com/howto/wp-content/uploads/2016/08/mini.jpg" height="75">
          </a>
           <!-- Menu Hamburguer -->
           <button class="navbar-toggler" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#nav-principal">
             <i class="fas fa-bars text-white"></i>
           </button>
           <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="nav-principal">
               <ul class="navbar-nav navbar-light ml-auto">
                 <li class="nav-item">
                   <a href="" class="nav-link"> Início </a>
                 </li>
                 <li class="nav-item">
                   <a href="" class="nav-link"> A Clínica </a>
                 </li>
                 <li class="nav-item">
                   <a href="" class="nav-link"> Tratamentos </a>
                 </li>
                 <li class="nav-item">
                   <a href="" class="nav-link"> Promoções </a>
                 </li>
                 <li class="nav-item">
                   <a href="" class="nav-link"> Contato </a>
                 </li>
               </ul>
             </div>
             <!-- Fim do Menu -->
      </div>
    </nav>
  </header>
  <!-- Fim do Cabeçalho -->
```

Comment: Obrigado, a solução foi muito eficiente e fez o efeito que eu queria com a media!

Answer (score 0):

Uma opção é na `div` que vc coloco a classe `container`, não use essa classe, substitua `container` por `mx-auto` e adicione tb a classe `text-center`. Com isso vc terá o resultado como abaixo. *Não precisa de CSS estra ou de @medias para essa opção. Mas seria interessante vc dar mais detalhes de como imagina a responsividade*

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Segue o código da imagem acima:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
<meta charset="utf-8" />
<title>Page Title</title>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="screen" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.2.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="screen" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/5.8.2/css/all.min.css" />
<style>

</style>
</head>

<body>

    <!-- Início do Cabeçalho -->
    <header>
        <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-md bg-warning">
            <div class="mx-auto text-center">
                <!-- Logo do Site -->
                <a href="index.html" class="navbar-brand">
                    <img src="https://unsplash.it/100/75" height="75">
                </a>
                <!-- Menu Hamburguer -->
                <button class="navbar-toggler" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#nav-principal">
                    <i class="fas fa-bars text-white"></i>
                </button>
                <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="nav-principal">
                    <ul class="navbar-nav navbar-light ml-auto">
                        <li class="nav-item">
                            <a href="" class="nav-link"> Início </a>
                        </li>
                        <li class="nav-item">
                            <a href="" class="nav-link"> A Clínica </a>
                        </li>
                        <li class="nav-item">
                            <a href="" class="nav-link"> Tratamentos </a>
                        </li>
                        <li class="nav-item">
                            <a href="" class="nav-link"> Promoções </a>
                        </li>
                        <li class="nav-item">
                            <a href="" class="nav-link"> Contato </a>
                        </li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
                <!-- Fim do Menu -->
            </div>
        </nav>
    </header>

    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.12.9/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.2.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Obrigado pelo código, deu certo! Na questão da responsividade quando chegasse nos breakpoints sm e md eu gostaria de tentar alinhar a logo para esquerda e o toggle icon para a direita, ai precisaria utilizar os @medias?

Comment: A solução do rapaz acima atendeu isso que eu queria, mas muito obrigado pela atenção e pela ajuda!

Comment: @IgorPereira talvez seja possível sim, mas vc via ter que dar uma pesquisada nas classes flex da documentação do bootstrap https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.3/utilities/flex/